# Swashbuckle C# swagger plugin how to use my own personal swagger.json by default instead of relying on one it generates?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I ran into an issue on a project I am on where for various reasons we were unable to rely on swashbuckle to generate the swagger.json we needed for the project and had to write it ourselves by hand. I have been searching all over the place but have been unable to figure out how to configure it so that when people type /swagger in the home url, it defaults to my swagger.json file instead of the one auto-generated by swashbuckle that will not work for us. Users are forced to manually change to mine by typing the filepath to it in the "swagger url bar" at the top of the UI which leads to a lot of confusion.

Can anyone share the code / settings needed to do this? (assuming I can) or suggest a better swagger library (that has clear documentation on how to implement) if this is not possible? I have searched tons of articles trying to resolve the issue to no avail. We already have the swagger.json file done we just need a viable way to make it the default file when a user types /swagger.

Our current SwaggerConfig is mostly just the default settings and looks like:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {

                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\SwaggerAPI.XML",
                     System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                    // By default, the service root url is inferred from the request used to access the docs.
                    // However, there may be situations (e.g. proxy and load-balanced environments) where this does not
                    // resolve correctly. You can workaround this by providing your own code to determine the root URL.
                    //
                    //c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig());

                    // If schemes are not explicitly provided in a Swagger 2.0 document, then the scheme used to access
                    // the docs is taken as the default. If your API supports multiple schemes and you want to be explicit
                    // about them, you can use the "Schemes" option as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });

                    // Use "SingleApiVersion" to describe a single version API. Swagger 2.0 includes an "Info" object to
                    // hold additional metadata for an API. Version and title are required but you can also provide
                    // additional fields by chaining methods off SingleApiVersion.
                    //

                    // If your API has multiple versions, use "MultipleApiVersions" instead of "SingleApiVersion".
                    // In this case, you must provide a lambda that tells Swashbuckle which actions should be
                    // included in the docs for a given API version. Like "SingleApiVersion", each call to "Version"
                    // returns an "Info" builder so you can provide additional metadata per API version.
                    //
                    //c.MultipleApiVersions(
                    //    (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(apiDesc, targetApiVersion),
                    //    (vc) =>
                    //    {
                    //        vc.Version("v2", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V2");
                    //        vc.Version("v1", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V1");
                    //    });

                    // You can use "BasicAuth", "ApiKey" or "OAuth2" options to describe security schemes for the API.
                    // See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md for more details.
                    // NOTE: These only define the schemes and need to be coupled with a corresponding "security" property
                    // at the document or operation level to indicate which schemes are required for an operation. To do this,
                    // you'll need to implement a custom IDocumentFilter and/or IOperationFilter to set these properties
                    // according to your specific authorization implementation
                    //
                    //c.BasicAuth("basic")
                    //    .Description("Basic HTTP Authentication");
                    //
                    c.ApiKey("apiKey")
                        .Description("API Key Authentication")
                        .Name("Authorization")
                        .In("header");

                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "PervasiveAPI");

                    //
                    //c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                    //    .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                    //    .Flow("implicit")
                    //    .AuthorizationUrl("http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/oauth/dialog")
                    //    //.TokenUrl("https://tempuri.org/token")
                    //    .Scopes(scopes =>
                    //    {
                    //        scopes.Add("read", "Read access to protected resources");
                    //        scopes.Add("write", "Write access to protected resources");
                    //    });

                    // Set this flag to omit descriptions for any actions decorated with the Obsolete attribute
                    //c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();

                    // Each operation be assigned one or more tags which are then used by consumers for various reasons.
                    // For example, the swagger-ui groups operations according to the first tag of each operation.
                    // By default, this will be controller name but you can use the "GroupActionsBy" option to
                    // override with any value.
                    //
                    //c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.HttpMethod.ToString());

                    // You can also specify a custom sort order for groups (as defined by "GroupActionsBy") to dictate
                    // the order in which operations are listed. For example, if the default grouping is in place
                    // (controller name) and you specify a descending alphabetic sort order, then actions from a
                    // ProductsController will be listed before those from a CustomersController. This is typically
                    // used to customize the order of groupings in the swagger-ui.
                    //
                    //c.OrderActionGroupsBy(new DescendingAlphabeticComparer());

                    // Swashbuckle makes a best attempt at generating Swagger compliant JSON schemas for the various types
                    // exposed in your API. However, there may be occasions when more control of the output is needed.
                    // This is supported through the "MapType" and "SchemaFilter" options:
                    //
                    // Use the "MapType" option to override the Schema generation for a specific type.
                    // It should be noted that the resulting Schema will be placed "inline" for any applicable Operations.
                    // While Swagger 2.0 supports inline definitions for "all" Schema types, the swagger-ui tool does not.
                    // It expects "complex" Schemas to be defined separately and referenced. For this reason, you should only
                    // use the "MapType" option when the resulting Schema is a primitive or array type. If you need to alter a
                    // complex Schema, use a Schema filter.
                    //
                    //c.MapType<ProductType>(() => new Schema { type = "integer", format = "int32" });
                    //
                    // If you want to post-modify "complex" Schemas once they've been generated, across the board or for a
                    // specific type, you can wire up one or more Schema filters.
                    //
                    //c.SchemaFilter<ApplySchemaVendorExtensions>();

                    // Set this flag to omit schema property descriptions for any type properties decorated with the
                    // Obsolete attribute 
                    //c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();

                    // In a Swagger 2.0 document, complex types are typically declared globally and referenced by unique
                    // Schema Id. By default, Swashbuckle does NOT use the full type name in Schema Ids. In most cases, this
                    // works well because it prevents the "implementation detail" of type namespaces from leaking into your
                    // Swagger docs and UI. However, if you have multiple types in your API with the same class name, you'll
                    // need to opt out of this behavior to avoid Schema Id conflicts.
                    //
                    //c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();

                    // In accordance with the built in JsonSerializer, Swashbuckle will, by default, describe enums as integers.
                    // You can change the serializer behavior by configuring the StringToEnumConverter globally or for a given
                    // enum type. Swashbuckle will honor this change out-of-the-box. However, if you use a different
                    // approach to serialize enums as strings, you can also force Swashbuckle to describe them as strings.
                    // 
                    //c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

                    // Similar to Schema filters, Swashbuckle also supports Operation and Document filters:
                    //
                    // Post-modify Operation descriptions once they've been generated by wiring up one or more
                    // Operation filters.
                    //
                    //c.OperationFilter<AddDefaultResponse>();
                    //
                    // If you've defined an OAuth2 flow as described above, you could use a custom filter
                    // to inspect some attribute on each action and infer which (if any) OAuth2 scopes are required
                    // to execute the operation
                    //
                    //c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();

                    // Post-modify the entire Swagger document by wiring up one or more Document filters.
                    // This gives full control to modify the final SwaggerDocument. You should have a good understanding of
                    // the Swagger 2.0 spec. - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md
                    // before using this option.
                    //
                    //c.DocumentFilter<ApplyDocumentVendorExtensions>();

                    // If you annonate Controllers and API Types with
                    // Xml comments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.110).aspx), you can incorporate
                    // those comments into the generated docs and UI. You can enable this by providing the path to one or
                    // more Xml comment files.
                    //
                    //c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

                    // In contrast to WebApi, Swagger 2.0 does not include the query string component when mapping a URL
                    // to an action. As a result, Swashbuckle will raise an exception if it encounters multiple actions
                    // with the same path (sans query string) and HTTP method. You can workaround this by providing a
                    // custom strategy to pick a winner or merge the descriptions for the purposes of the Swagger docs 
                    //
                    //c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {

                    // Use the "InjectStylesheet" option to enrich the UI with one or more additional CSS stylesheets.
                    // The file must be included in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's
                    // "Logical Name" is passed to the method as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.InjectStylesheet(containingAssembly, "Swashbuckle.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testStyles1.css");

                    // Use the "InjectJavaScript" option to invoke one or more custom JavaScripts after the swagger-ui
                    // has loaded. The file must be included in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's
                    // "Logical Name" is passed to the method as shown above.
                    //
                    //c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Swashbuckle.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testScript1.js");

                    // The swagger-ui renders boolean data types as a dropdown. By default, it provides "true" and "false"
                    // strings as the possible choices. You can use this option to change these to something else,
                    // for example 0 and 1.
                    //
                    //c.BooleanValues(new[] { "0", "1" });

                    // By default, swagger-ui will validate specs against swagger.io's online validator and display the result
                    // in a badge at the bottom of the page. Use these options to set a different validator URL or to disable the
                    // feature entirely.
                    //c.SetValidatorUrl("http://localhost/validator");
                    //c.DisableValidator();

                    // Use this option to control how the Operation listing is displayed.
                    // It can be set to "None" (default), "List" (shows operations for each resource),
                    // or "Full" (fully expanded: shows operations and their details).
                    //
                    //c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);

                    // Use the CustomAsset option to provide your own version of assets used in the swagger-ui.
                    // It's typically used to instruct Swashbuckle to return your version instead of the default
                    // when a request is made for "index.html". As with all custom content, the file must be included
                    // in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's "Logical Name" is passed to
                    // the method as shown below.
                    //
                   // c.CustomAsset("index", containingAssembly, "swaggerdocs.json");

                    // If your API has multiple versions and you've applied the MultipleApiVersions setting
                    // as described above, you can also enable a select box in the swagger-ui, that displays
                    // a discovery URL for each version. This provides a convenient way for users to browse documentation
                    // for different API versions.
                    //
                    //c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();

                    // If your API supports the OAuth2 Implicit flow, and you've described it correctly, according to
                    // the Swagger 2.0 specification, you can enable UI support as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.EnableOAuth2Support("test-client-id", "test-realm", "Swagger UI");
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discovery paths parameter in the SwaggerEnabledConfiguration constructor allows you to change where SwaggerUI finds the OpenAPI description document.

```
 public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var swaggerEnabledConfig = new SwaggerEnabledConfiguration(config, SwaggerDocsConfig.DefaultRootUrlResolver, new[] { "swaggerdocs.json" });  // Empty string causes "undefined" to appear
            swaggerEnabledConfig.EnableSwaggerUi();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more of how to use this? Say I have a path in my root directory for /swaggerdocs.json. How do I use this to make it default to that json file when I type /swagger in the URL instead of the one it generated?

I either don't see where in this the filepath is explicitly set or I don't fully understand how to use the code you supplied.

Comment: @WanderingCoder I updated the example to what I believe will work for your case.

Comment: I updated my post to include my current swaggerconfig. I am not sure how to implement the one you propose above, I tried doing it as an overload but I got ambiguous type errors, when I tried changing the base Register() to match yours I got parameter errors. I don't explicitly call Register() anywhere in the code, as far as I can tell its called by the built in WebActivator.dll. What changes do I need to make to use this? And what exactly should get passed to config?

Comment: [TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +12958016
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +54
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +21
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +236
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +619

Comment: I deleted my SwaggerConfig class entirely to use what you had above, and received the stack trace shown above

Comment: @WanderingCoder  Hmm strange.  Maybe I did some other stuff.  The code is here https://github.com/darrelmiller/conference-api/blob/master/ConferenceApiApp/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs

Comment: my swaggerconfig has the following line at the top

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

this is what throws the error, but removing it makes /swagger do nothing, its like swagger isnt initialized at all. how does your code run without it?

Comment: I figured it out, you pass things in your global, instead of using the preassembly

Answer (score 2):

Use an IDocumentFilter:

```
    private class CustomDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry sr, IApiExplorer ae)
        {
            // Code here
        }
    }
```

with that you can modify the swaggerDoc to suit your needs

I have a bunch of examples here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs