# Can I use Swashbuckle with my own OpenAPI Specification Json?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, openapi

I am trying to add Swagger documentation to my existing .Net (not core) API. I understand that Swashbuckle is a valuable tool for generating the Json which the Swagger UI uses, however the Json that Swashbuckle generates for my API is not great and it would be simpler to write my own Json specification. On the other hand, Swashbuckle's integration of the Swagger-UI into my API's codebase is really convenient.

Is there any way to simply point the Swagger-UI to my own Json rather then generating one with Swashbuckle or am I better off foregoing Swashbuckle all together?

Any guidance here would be great! Thanks

Comment: This is just a hunch but when you specify the swagger endpoint using `SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json","MyApi")`  would it not be possible to point it to a route that is serving your own version of the json?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45906183/542240

Comment: @MNVR yes! thank you

Answer (score 0):

The method described here: [stackoverflow.com/a/45906183/542240](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45906183/542240) will work however I would like to know how to achieve the same result using IDocumentFilter described in the second answer.